# Google Sheets Formula to Count Occurrences of Unique Values in Columns

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I'm looking for a formula, =query possibly, that will turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

I used the following formula successfully to get the AFTER picture, but I can't get the counts. I tried using concatenate but there isn't a way to do that to each item in the array. Maybe there is a way to do this using a query?

```
=transpose(split(join(",",unique(C1:C98)),","))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And here's my flavour of it, which also needs to be dragged to the right, to fill the other columns:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
   {UNIQUE(A$2:A) & " - " & COUNTIF(A$2:A,UNIQUE(A$2:A))},
   "where Col1<>' - 0'",0))
```

[image]

Comment: `where Col1<>' - 0'` That is clever. Kudos.

Comment: @marikamitsos Thanks!  I realised I had to clean it up somehow when I first saw the output...

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use query to get the unique values and counts then join the two columns

```
=ArrayFormula(index(query(A2:A,"select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A) ''"),0,1)&"-"&index(query(A2:A,"select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A) ''"),0,2))
```

[image]

Apologies, in order to drag it across you would have to put:

```
=ArrayFormula(index(query({A2:A},"select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1) ''"),0,1)
&"-"&index(query({A2:A},"select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1) ''"),0,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in cell `A2` and drag to the right.

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(CONCAT(UNIQUE(A2:A99)&" - ", 
                 ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(A2:A99,UNIQUE(A2:A99)))))),COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A99),1)
```

[image]

Also using a query

```
=ArrayFormula(index(query({A2:A},"select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1) ''"),0,1)&"-"& 
              index(query({A2:A},"select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1) ''"),0,2))
```

The only difference is that using the first formula you maintain the names within the order they appear, while using the query they get sorted alphabetically.

Functions used:

- [`ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592)
- [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198)
- [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550)
- [`COUNTUNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093405)